# Pegar informações da faixa de música com JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, node.js, html5-audio

Estou fazendo um player de música usando apenas HTML, CSS e JavaScript. Consigo fazer tudo, exceto pegar as informações da faixa.
Consigo pegar a duração da faixa e também o tempo atual, as informações que preciso são coisas do tipo autor, ano de lançamento, arte do álbum, nome do álbum...
Alguém sabe como fazer isso e, se sabe, como?
:)

Comment: Sem um exemplo de como está seu serviço e seu cliente fica bem difícil de se sugerir uma solução

Answer (score 2):

Você pode obter essa dados através das tags [ID3](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) dos ficheiros mp3, mas para ler essa informação terá de usar as APIs [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) e [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).

Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').onchange = function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var dv = new jDataView(this.result);

    // "TAG" starts at byte -128 from EOF.
    // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3
    if (dv.getString(3, dv.byteLength - 128) == 'TAG') {
      var title = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
      var artist = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
      var album = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
      var year = dv.getString(4, dv.tell());
    } else {
      // no ID3v1 data found.
    }
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
};
```

Trecho de código retirado de [Reading .mp3 ID3 tags in JavaScript](https://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript)

Atenção que o exemplo acima faz uso da biblioteca [jDataView](https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView) para facilitar a manipulação com a API `DataView`

Caso esteja a usar `nodejs` pode utilizar um de muitos pacotes do node para te auxiliar no processo.
Exemplo com o pacote [id3-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/id3-parser):

```
import { parse } from 'id3-parser';
import { convertFileToBuffer, fetchFileAsBuffer } from 'id3-parser/lib/universal/helpers';
import universalParse from 'id3-parser/lib/universal';

// You have a File instance in browser
convertFileToBuffer(file).then(parse).then(tag => {
    console.log(tag);
});
// Or a remote mp3 file url
fetchFileAsBuffer(url).then(parse).then(tag => {
    console.log(tag);
});

// Or a smarter parse
universalParse(file|url|bytes).then(tag => {
    console.log(tag);
});
```

Comment: Cara, estou tentando usar o primeiro exemplo que você postou há algum tempo. Dá erro na biblioteca jDataView (que é externa). Vou tentar usar o exemplo com o node.